# Как объединить 2 mysql запроса не прибегая к циклическим подзапросам

Tags: mysql

День добрый.
Имеется база данных со следующей структурой:

таблица **log**:

```
| guid | uid | Type | BoxID |
|------|-----|------|-------| 
|  1   |  1  |   1  |   1   |
|  2   |  1  |  -1  |   1   |
|  3   |  2  |   1  |   1   |
|  3   |  2  |   1  |   2   |
|  3   |  2  |  -1  |   2   |
|  4   |  1  |   1  |   3   |
|  5   |  1  |  -1  |   3   |
|  6   |  1  |   1  |   3   |
|  7   |  2  |   1  |   3   |
|  8   |  2  |   1  |   5   |
|  9   |  2  |  -1  |   5   |
|  10  |  1  |   1  |   5   |
```

для каждого **BoxID**

таблица box:

```
| BoxID | isOne |
|-------|-------|
|   1   |   1   |
|   2   |   0   |
|   3   |   1   |
|   4   |   0   |
|   5   |   1   |
|   6   |   1   |
```

Задача стоит следующая: нужно для каждого отдельно взятого uid получить список всех BoxID с параметром isOne = 1 из таблицы box, при условии что BoxID добавляется в результирующий список когда выполняется одно из условий:
1) в таблице log нет записей с этими uid и BoxID 
2) в таблице log есть записи с этими uid и BoxID, но сумма Type этих записей <= 0. 
В запрос подается только uid. Из приведенного примера таблиц для uid = 1 должен браться BoxID = 1, т.к. для него сумма Type = 0 для uid = 1 и BoxID = 6, т.к. для него при uid = 1 записей в log нет.
Т.е. результат должен быть следующий:

При uid = 1: BoxID = [1, 6]

При uid = 2: BoxID = [5, 6]

Сам список боксов для которых нужна проверка выдергиваю запросом:

```
SELECT b.BoxID FROM box as b WHERE b.isOne = 1
```

проверяю сумму Type следующим запросом:

```
SET @cnt := 0;
SET @num := 0;
SELECT l.BoxID, (@num := @num + 1) as num, (@cnt := @cnt + a.Type) as cnt FROM log as l WHERE l.BoxID = 1 AND l.uid = 1 ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1
```

По сути подобную проверку можно организовать циклическим запросом для каждого обнаруженного BoxId со значением isOne = 1 из php, однако это весьма непрятно и костыльно.

Возможно ли объединить эти запросы в один так, чтобы решить поставленную задачу без дополнительных запросов из php? Т.е. отправить 1 запрос со значением uid и получить готовый список BoxID удовлетворяющих условиям.

Comment: Покажите эталонный ответ на ЭТИХ ДАННЫХ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT b.BoxID, SUM(l.Type) as type_sum
FROM log l
JOIN box b ON b. BoxID=l.BoxID
WHERE l.uid={id} AND b.isOne=1
GROUP BY b.BoxID
HAVING type_sum<=1
```

Comment: Там еще `count(1) as num` судя по исходным запросам. И LEFT уберите, должен быть обычный join, все равно вы весь эффект от LEFT (даже если бы он был нужен) убиваете в части where

Comment: К сожалению указанный запрос добавляет BoxID  в список только в том случае, если он присутствует в таблице log. Если его там нет, то он в список не включается. Нужно чтобы такие BoxID  так же включались в список. Прошу прощения, изначально не указал этот момент в задаче. Пробовал без left и пробовал переписать без join - результат не принесло

Comment: Условие `AND b.isOne=1` следует переместить в секцию `ON` - ведь отбор по нему должен выполняться ДО связывания.

Comment: @StraykerWl у вас обязательное условие выборки l.uid. Как-то не согласуется с дополнением.

Comment: @Akina если переместить в ON , то можем получить часть строк с b.*=null. А вот вариант про join(inner join) как раз и устраняет эту проблему

Comment: @ChipX При INNER JOIN не будет выполнено альтернативное условие *либо если для этого uid нет записей в таблице log с этим BoxID*.

Comment: @Akina это условие не имеет смысла, так как отсутствие записи в log автоматом не попадает под условие с uid

Comment: @ChipX Ерунда. Счас придёт автор и поправит свою опечатку. Он явно имел в виду, что ему нужны записи из таблицы log, не имеющие связанных записей в таблице BoxID.

Comment: Тогда задача изначально не правильно сформулирована или автор до конца не представляет условия выборки

Comment: Да, действительно расписал весьма путанно, прошу прощения.
Проблему удалось решить, добавив к предоставленному ChipX следующий запрос

`'union
(SELECT b.BoxID, 0 as type_sum
FROM box as b
WHERE b.isOne = 1 AND b.BoxID NOT IN (SELECT l.BoxID FROM log as l WHERE b.BoxID = l.BoxID AND l.uid = 13))`

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь всем!